# Need to grep /etc/hosts with a known hostname, and then capture the ip address for the hostname from /etc/hosts

Tags: regex, linux, bash, dns, hosts

Need to grep /etc/hosts with a known hostname, and then capture the ip address for the hostname from /etc/hosts.

I am not a programmer, and don't know how to go about this.  I have very limited experience with regex, but think that this might work somehow.  I am not using DNS, just managing with /etc/hosts file.

I need to grep the /etc/hosts file with the known hostname, and then capture the IP address for the hosts entry.  The host file is standard format:

Please help!

## UPDATE:

`#` Maintenance Network

```
192.168.80.192  testsrv01-maint
192.168.80.193  testsrv02-maint
192.168.80.194  testsrv03-maint
```

`#` Lights Out Network

```
192.168.120.192  testsrv01-ilo
192.168.120.193  testsrv02-ilo
192.168.120.194  testsrv03-ilo
```

`#` Primary Data Network

```
192.168.150.192  testsrv01-pri
192.168.150.193  testsrv02-pri
192.168.150.194  testsrv03-pri
```

`#` Secondary Data Network

```
192.168.200.192  testsrv01-sec
192.168.200.193  testsrv02-sec
192.168.200.194  testsrv03-sec
```

I need to be able to capture the ip address and full host name entry for every machine into a variable that I can use.  For instance run through the file looking to match " testsrv01* ", and capture all of the ip addresses and name for that search.  Then same for  " testsrv02* " , and so on.

Comment: The first two response seem to work great.  I neglected to mention that there are some machines that have multiple entries into the /etc/hosts file.  I need to capture each entry, with IP ADDRESS field and the HOSTNAME field.

For Example:
192.168.0.1    example1.domain
192.168.0.2    example1.another.domain

192.168.100.1  example2.domain
192.168.150.5  example2.another.domain

Comment: In that case, please update your question with a sample `/etc/hosts` file and be more exact about the output you want for the scenario (a) one matching IP for a hostname and (b) more than one matching IP.

Comment: No, you don't need to do this. You need to use the `nslookup` command, or, if you're programming, one of the DNS functions provided for the purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Simple answer**

`ip=$(grep 'www.example.com' /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}')`

---

**Better answer**
The simple answer returns all matching IP, even those on comment lines.  You probably only want the first non-comment match, in which case just use awk outright:

`ip=$(awk '/^[[:space:]]*($|#)/{next} /www.example.com/{print $1; exit}' /etc/hosts)`

---

**One other thing** If you, at some point, care to resolve www.example.com whether your system is configured to use hosts, dns, etc, then consider the lesser known `getent` command:

`ip=$(getent hosts 'www.example.com' | awk '{print $1}')`

---

**Edit in response to update**

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

host_to_find=${1:?"Please tell me what host you want to find"}

while read ip host; do
    echo "IP=[$ip] and host=[$host]"
done < <(awk "/^[[:space:]]*($|#)/{next} /$host_to_find/{print \$1 \" \" \$2}" /etc/hosts)

$ ./script.sh testsrv01
IP=[192.168.80.192] and host=[testsrv01-maint]
IP=[192.168.120.192] and host=[testsrv01-ilo]
IP=[192.168.150.192] and host=[testsrv01-pri]
IP=[192.168.200.192] and host=[testsrv01-sec]
```

Comment: `grep|awk` is almost always useless. `awk '/www.example.com/{print $1}' /etc/hosts`

Comment: Might want to add `$1 ~ /^#/ { next }` as the first line of the Awk script to skip any comments.

Comment: @tripleee: Oh, I know, but OP so deliberately asked to grep. :)  Good call on the comments, too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `grep` with a [Perl regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) to output the IP of your target hostname.

```
grep -oP '^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?=.*hostname)' /etc/hosts
```

Explanation:

- `^` finds the start of a line
- `\d{1,3}` finds one through three digits
- `\.` finds a dot
- `(?=something)` finds `something` but doesn't include it in the match ("[zero-width positive look-ahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)")
- `.` without a preceding backslash finds any character
- `*` repeats the preceding expression (in this case "any character") zero or more times

In other words, this will find a series of four one through three-digit numbers separated by dots, and print them (`grep -o`) if they are followed by any string and then `hostname`), all on this on one line.

Comment: +1 for using `-o` and positive look-ahead. I'd recommend `-m 1` to limit to the first match.  Also, note that this won't work for IPv6 addresses which might be in `/etc/hosts` (though the OP didn't state he needed v6).