# Bash: write a function that checks if a given hostname exists in /etc/hosts

Tags: bash, awk, hosts

I am trying to write a function in bash that checks if a given `hostname` is present in `/etc/hosts`. Comments and partial matches should not count. In other words, it should only return `0` if *exactly* the specified `hostname` was found. This is what I got so far:

```sh
check_host()
{
    AWK=$(awk '$1 ~ /^#/ { next } $2=="'$1'" {print $2}' /etc/hosts)
    if [ -n "$AWK" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

I would prefer to use `awk` or `grep` to get the solution.

The function worked on my smaller local file, but it somehow failed on bigger ones; I am unsure of the reason. What am I missing? How could I improve or simplify my function?

I've already checked the following answer, but it does not work as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25277451/157762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getent` command and pipe it to `awk`:

```
getent hosts | awk -v host="$HOSTNAME" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==host){print $i;e=1}}}END{exit !e}'
```

`awk` splits the line using sequences of spaces as the (default) separator and checks if it exactly matches the hostname. If found it prints the hostname and exits with `0`, otherwise it outputs nothing and exits with `1`.

`getent` has the advantage that it displays the local host information which is *in effect* on the system rather than parsing `/etc/hosts`. While this might be preferred for a lot of use cases, I can also imagine of use cases where it is indeed required to parse `/etc/hosts`. In that cases I would suggest to use a real parser for that, like mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/a/281995/166536)

**Former answer (wrong)**

You can use the `getent` command:

```
getent hosts | grep -wF HOSTNAME
```

However, this depends on the `hosts` setting in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, but it should work with the default configuration that ships with all Linux distros I'm aware of.

**Wrong because:** -w tells grep that the pattern should be enclosed by *word boundaries*, I was using it to make sure that `foo-bar` would not match the pattern `foo`. Unfortunately the hyphen *is* a word boundary!! (facepalm)

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely valid, but for those reasons I also want a solution involving either grep or awk or both.

Comment: Try to add `hostname` and `hostname-01` to `/etc/hosts`. `getent hosts | grep -wF hostname` returns both :(

Comment: Oh, I see. You are right. `-w` tells grep that the pattern should be enclosed by *word* boundaries. Unfortunately the hyphen *is* a word boundary.. Let me elaborate the command..

Comment: This will always exit 1, even if exit once after host is found, `END` block will be evaluated, try this `printf "1\n2\n" | awk '$1==1{exit 0}END{exit 12}'; echo $?` and exit code will be 12

Comment: This seems to work. I think `getent hosts` can be switched to `grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' /etc/hosts`. This will remove commented lines

Comment: They are not related, I am just saying that if that grep command is used instead of getent, it is an equivalent solution, although I expect it to be more expensive with grep.

Comment: @DanielSzalay Yes and no. Both command behaving differently. However `getent` will do more than just grep. It returns that settings that are currently in effect while simply parses `/etc/hosts`. What is *better* depends on what you have in mind with your program.

Comment: Instead of `awk -ve=1 '...{e=0}...END{exit e}` consider `awk '...{e=1}...END{exit !e}`. Btw not having a space between `-v` and the variable being initialized makes the script unnecessarily gawk-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this:

```
check_host() {
    [[ -n $(awk -v host="${1//./\\\\.}" '!/^[[:blank:]]*#/ { $1="" }
            $0 ~ "[[:blank:]]+" host "([[:blank:]]|$)"' /etc/hosts) ]]
}
```

**Testing:**

```
check_host localhost; echo $?
0

check_host foobar; echo $?
1
```

Comment: I think you missed `&&`

Comment: You can add multiple hosts per IP in `/etc/hosts`. `$2` would not work. You need to iterate over the columns

Comment: @anubhava What if a line contains `192.168.0.10 foo # was bar before`? When search for bar, your command returns a match. I mean, comments might appear at the end of the line.

Comment: As per the question OP was trying to check for comments only at beginning so that's what I also captured in my answer

Comment: @anubhava You are right strictly speaking this is what I specified in my question, I did not think of that edge case however :)

Comment: @anubhava Another thing: `host` will get handled as a regex, you need to sanitize regex special chars before using it. Check this for example: `awk -vhost='foo.bar' '$1 ~ host' <<< 'foo-bar'` - which returns a wrong match (and is a common use case).. I know, it is a pain in the a** :D

Comment: @DanielSzalay If you really want to check `/etc/hosts` instead of getting the information from `getent` like I've suggested, I would encourage you to use a real parser for the hostsfile. Like this: http://serverfault.com/a/281995/166536